# Show that Hessian matrix reduces to Laplacian in spherically symmetric integral

Tags: calculus, tensors, rotations, laplacian, symmetric-functions

TLDR: read the final paragraph. For my course I have to evaluate
$$\int_{S^2}d\vec R\ R_iR_j\frac{\partial^2G(\vec R)}{\partial R_i\partial R_j}$$
Here the Einstein summation convention is used, $G$ is a still unknown function, $\vec R$ is the position vector in $\mathbb R^3$ and we integrate over the unit sphere so $\vec R^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $d\vec R$ is just the surface element on the sphere.

To evaluate this the teaching assistent gave us the hint that we can assume $G$ is spherically symmetric. This means that any term with $i\neq j$ will vanish because you then integrate an odd function $R_iR_j$ over a symmetric domain. This means the integrand becomes
$$R_i^2\frac{\partial^2G(\vec R)}{\partial R_i^2}=x^2\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2}+y^2\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial y^2}+z^2\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial z^2}$$
The final step is that because of spherical symmetry we can replace $\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial y^2}=\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial z^2}=\frac 1 3\nabla^2G$ which will then greatly simplify the integral. I don't understand this last step so that's what my question is about. I tried to make sense of it but couldn't see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial y\partial x}$$

$$\eqalign{\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial x\partial y}&=\frac{\partial (G(\vec R+\Delta y\mathbf{\widehat j})-G(\vec R))}{\partial x}\\&=\frac{ G(\vec R + \Delta x\mathbf{\widehat i}+ \Delta y\mathbf{\widehat j})-G(\vec R + \Delta y\mathbf{\widehat j})- G(\vec R+\Delta x\mathbf{\widehat i})+G(\vec R)}{\Delta x}\\ &=\frac{G(\vec R + 2\Delta x\mathbf{\widehat i})-2G(\vec R + \Delta x\mathbf{\widehat j})+G(\vec R)}{\Delta x}=\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial^2 x} \;\; as \;\; \Delta x,\Delta y \rightarrow 0}$$

That's because of spherical symmetry that for example $G(\vec R+\Delta x\mathbf{\widehat i})=G(\vec R + \Delta y\mathbf{\widehat j})$

The same will go for $y \; \text{and} \; z$

Comment: So you show that the first partial derivatives are all equal? I don't understand your steps after 'Since'. Is $x^2+y^2+z^2$ just an example of a spherically symmetric function? It also seems like it's not a valid proof because $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2+z^2)=2x$ while $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2+y^2+z^2)=2y$

Comment: Right! Sorry it seems I have messed up with the proof...

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion I hope this answer explains it...